# Should "information required" be part of "unclear what you're asking"

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

Currently, when voting to close a question because *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*, you have to go through the option *off topic because*.

I don't think a question without information on how it should be used is off-topic, I think it is unclear. We have a separate close reason for *not clear what you are asking*.

So surely the *must include information* option should be a subset of *not clear what you are asking*.

Thoughts?

Comment: I think the only place custom close reasons can go is "off-topic".

Comment: "I don't a question..."... don't _what_ a question?

Comment: @Colleen is right. There are three "custom" close reasons the moderators of a site can add or modify, and all three go under the "off-topic" category. The other close reasons are standard: *POB, Unclear* and *Too Broad*. It's debatable whether one can equate *duplicate* and *migration* to closure.

Comment: Probably "I don't ***think*** a question..."

Comment: Related on [meta.se]: [Can we rename the off-topic close reason label on the primary screen?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186024/255554)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Off-topic" is very, very wide!

Anything which is explicitly off-topic, or even not on the "on-topic" list, is off-topic.

It's OK to say that questions which don't adhere to the published guidelines as stated in question tags are off-topic as well.

The tag guidance for [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) is very explicit, having undergone a number of revisions to improve it over the years.

If a question doesn't meet the tag guidelines for a single-word request, it's fine to mark it as off-topic: single-word requests must meet the guidelines.

This is quite apart from the technical limitations: custom close reasons can only go under "off-topic", so that's where this one is. In choosing the custom close reasons (again, over a number of years), the most common are: lack of research or too basic; proof-reading; incomplete SWR.

Comment: By the same argument, *unclear what you’re asking, too broad* and *primarily opinion-based* should be placed under off-topic as well.

Comment: @W That's a site-wide thing. You're welcome to post on Meta.SE with suggestions. I'm only attempting to rationalise what we have to use.

Comment: *That's a site-wide thing.* – I know. But that does not make your rationalisation valid. [A suggestion in that direction also already exists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/210314/255554). PS: [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186024/255554) is another one.

Comment: "Technical limitations" is a good enough answer for ELU Meta for me, which means it's an SE Meta query. @Wrzlprmft - thanks for the links to existing SE Meta queries, I've upvoted them.